Use Managed identity to access Azure Blob storage from an Azure VM
Below steps are configured.
1] Azure managed identity has been enabled for the vm
2] Access granted to Azure blob storage from the vm
I wanted to clarify what will be the next steps to access the blob and list down the directories.
Do we need to configure anything on the vm to use the credentials? is CLI mandatory if i just want to access directly via a python code?
Error message received :

Listing directories in container: optitex
ImdsCredential.get_token_info failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable.
ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token_info failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable.
Code I am using:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError

# Function to list directories in a container
def list_directories_in_blob_container(storage_account_name, container_name):
    try:
        # Create the BlobServiceClient using DefaultAzureCredential (for Managed Identity)
        # If DefaultAzureCredential fails, fall back to AzureCliCredential
        try:
            print('********')
            credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"DefaultAzureCredential failed: {e}")
            print("Falling back to Default Credential")
            credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)

        # Get the container client
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

        # List all blobs in the container and check for directories
        print(f"Listing directories in container: {container_name}")
        blob_list = container_client.walk_blobs()

        directories = set()

        for blob in blob_list:
            blob_path_parts = blob.name.split('/')
            if len(blob_path_parts) > 1:
                directories.add(blob_path_parts[0])

        # Display found directories
        if directories:
            print("Directories found:")
            for directory in sorted(directories):
                print(f" - {directory}")
        else:
            print("No directories found.")

    except ResourceNotFoundError:
        print(f"Container '{container_name}' not found in the storage account '{storage_account_name}'.")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"An error occurred: {ex}")

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    storage_account_name = "xxx"
    container_name = "xxx"

    list_directories_in_blob_container(storage_account_name, container_name)```


I tried using DefaultAzureCredential, below is the error i am getting.

Do I need to configure CLI/ Environment variables ?


DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot this issue.
ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable.
SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path
AzurePowerShellCredential: Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed
AzureDeveloperCliCredential: Azure Developer CLI could not be found. Please visit https://aka.ms/azure-dev for installation instructions and then,once installed, authenticate to your Azure account using 'azd auth login'.

managed identity credential will work on Azure environment.

You can go with Defaultazurecredential by login in with cli command az login in your local environement.

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

I tried using defaultazurecredential, still failing, i have added the error from the code. Do we need to configure any environment variables for these?

You can be able to set environmental variables if you are authenticating with Azure AD authentication.

i tried login through az login --identity to use system identity for login, but its failing with below error.
"FAILED TO CONNECT TO MSI, HTTP 404 BAD REQUEST"
Seems like a firewall block on management.azure.com.

@Venkatesan is there a way to specify a proxy while retrieving credentials from the python code? I am getting blocked due to firewall restrictions when calling defaultazure credentials()

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal

Have you tried below to initializate credential?
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()

# Can also specify a client ID of a user-assigned managed identity
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(
   client_id="<client_id>",
)

reference


Use Managed identity to access Azure Blob storage from an Azure VM

According to this SO-Answer by Allen Wu.
Both system and user managed identity is not supported with ManagedIdentityCredential in the local environment.
In case you want to use a user-asigned managed identity with the DefaultAzureCredential when deployed to Azure, specify the clientId.
I tried with below modified code it worked in my environment and also assign Storage blob data contributor role to the identity.
Code:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


def list_directories_in_blob_container(storage_account_name, container_name):
    try:
        client_id=""
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        print(f"Listing directories in container: {container_name}")
        blob_list = container_client.walk_blobs()

        directories = set()
        for blob in blob_list:
            blob_path_parts = blob.name.split('/')
            if len(blob_path_parts) > 1:
                directories.add(blob_path_parts[0])

        if directories:
            print("Directories found:")
            for directory in sorted(directories):
                print(f" - {directory}")
        else:
            print("No directories found.")

    except ResourceNotFoundError:
        print(f"Container '{container_name}' not found in the storage account '{storage_account_name}'.")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"An error occurred: {ex}")

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    storage_account_name = "venkat326123"
    container_name = "data"

    list_directories_in_blob_container(storage_account_name, container_name)

Output:
Listing directories in container: data
Directories found:
 - samplehub1
 - test


Reference:
Azure Identity client library for Python | Microsoft Learn

I keep seeing the suggestion to use DefaultAzureCredential and yet when I pass it to BlobServiceClient I get the warning that it's not the right type and it doesn't seem to work. The correct types are listed as: credential: str | dict[str, str] | AzureNamedKeyCredential | AzureSasCredential | TokenCredential | None

The current docs reflect this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python

@eltiare See here TokenCredential we are passing has DefaultAzureCredential refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python

@Venkaestan Have you attempted to run this code yourself? I stated the error I was getting when attempting to use DefaultAzureCredential with the latest package. DefaultAzureCredential inherits from ChainedTokenCredential which doesn't inherit from anything.

@eltiare Can you post this as new question with more in detail?

There is no reason to do that. The docs you posted are wrong for the current libraries. Either something changed or someone made a bad assumption.

I am sorry what is client_id in the code?

Client_id  is your managed identity identity.
